# Reference frames of Odometry Message

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm just learning ROS and would like to ask your help to clarify something I'm totally confused by. In [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) the [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message is explained as follows:

> The pose in this message corresponds to the estimated position of the robot in the odometric frame [....] The twist in this message corresponds to the robot's velocity in the child frame, normally the coordinate frame of the mobile base [....]

The robot's *velocity* in the *mobile base* frame should be always zero, shouldn't it? (Because the *pose* of the robot in the *mobile base* frame is constant.) I think I fundamentally misunderstand the concept. Could someone please explain why it is a good idea to use different reference frames for `pose` and `twist`? I thought the Odometry message was used to describe the robot's position and velocity (both linear and angular) in the *odom frame*, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Thank you,
-Tamás

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341161/reference-frames-of-odometry-message/) by [tbondar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50735/tbondar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-01-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is already a similar question [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/310750/clarification-publishing-nav_msgsodometry-twist/) regarding this.

It can be a bit confusing, but according to the convention (it was maybe in [REP 105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)) and the [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message description, the twist should be in the `base_link`. It actually makes sense to consider the twist locally. For example, lets say the robot is moving with `1m/s` forward. A twist, with linear `x=1m/s` makes sense in this case regarding the `base_link` and the robots current velocity. Otherwise if it was in the parent (`odom`) frame then this simple movement would be represented with a combination of `x` and `y` regarding the robot's orientation in the `odom` frame.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2020-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2